# Suspension seatpost for mountain biking?

Tags: mountain-bike, product-rec

I've seen several seatposts on the market with suspension built into them such as the Thudbuster, Redshift, and Kinect and was wondering if anyone is using one for mountain biking?

Is it worth the money and does it improve the ride quality?

Let me know your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it worth getting a suspension seat post as a cheap alternative to full suspension bike?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/is-it-worth-getting-a-suspension-seat-post-as-a-cheap-alternative-to-full-suspen) Although not an exact dup, there are other Suspension seatpost questions (use search) that in combination will answer this.

Comment: At the moment this seems like a duplicate but what sort of mountain biking? On MTB trails you're out of the saddle enough that you won't get much use out of a suspension seatpost. On many forest tracks you don't need suspension at all but it might be nice for comfort, and this includes a suspension seatpost

Comment: I would say whilst this is borderline duplicate, a lot has changed in MTB technology since 2012 and a fresh look at the issue is warranted.

Comment: Geoff, could you update your post with details of what bike you intend to fit the seatpost to and elaborate more on that type of mountain biking you are doing?

Comment: @GrigoryRechistov Thanks for the answer. I've also looked around for some combination of the two (suspension and dropper). There doesn't seem to be anything out there like this and I'm wondering if this has to do with weight or just like you were saying that you would rather have a rigid post than a suspension post to begin with. Regardless, would be interesting to see this on the market.

Comment: As on whether a seat post that has both adjustability and suspension exists, remember that besides a technical feasibility, a product has to have a market niche to be reasonable to manufacture. I tried to show in my answer that a) areas of use for droppers and suspension posts do not overlap significantly, b) same effects of rear suspension can be achieved through clever frame design (rear shock, flexy chainstays, elastomers)

Answer (score 4):

It is more common for modern mountainbikers to use adjustable, or dropper posts, rather than suspension posts, both on hardtail and full suspension bikes.

The difference is that a dropper post's length can be  dynamically varied with a lever press, but without pressing it there is no spring action what so ever. This way, the rider's center of gravity can be lowered on rough and steep descents, but pedaling efficiency can be returned back whenever needed at the post's full extension.

In contrast, a suspension post has a fixed length and saddle position oscillating around that length with help of a spring of some sort. It is typically used for comfort riding or touring long distances on rough roads.

No modern high-grade modern mountain bike known to me comes with a suspension post, but a lot come with a dropper post.

> Is it worth the money

It is only for you to decide.

> does it improve the ride quality?

Having a bit of something to smooth road chatter is always welcome. Think about the trade-offs however: higher weight, higher cost, need for maintenance, and occasional return spring action smashing the saddle into your crotch (a spring saves kinetic energy only to give it back later). For mountain biking, where road chatter is not an issue, I would always prefer a dropper or even a classic rigid seat post to a suspension post. For a 100+km gravel road ride, I would go with a suspension post.

I want also to add that a suspension post is likely redundant on a full suspension MTB because there already is a spring at the rear of the bike that should provide similar, if not that pronounced, effect. For hardtails, modern frame designs attempt to build limited amount of flex into rear parts of frames (seatstays) to fulfill the same purpose of filtering out the road chatter getting to the saddle.

Comment: +1 but I don't think it's the rear suspension that replaces the suspension in the seatpost, but the tyres. The rear suspension is reasonably stiff and designed to take out big hits rather than high frequency stuff.

Comment: @ChrisH fair point, indeed, rear shock's main goal is **not** to remove high frequency chatter. However, I do believe that it does so as a side effect in most cases, unless the user specifically tunes it not to. Maybe it does it not as efficiently as say a 80 mm travel Thudbuster. Will edit the last paragraph to make it less "harsh"

Comment: If you add a paragraph about Fat bikes I will give you an up vote :)

Comment: @mattnz What can I add more? Fatbikes are awesome, they have "suspension" front and back, but they bounce. Both dropper posts (I use one) and suspension posts can be found on them.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of a suspension post is different than that of suspension fork & rear suspension. Suspension fork & rear suspension is to absorb impacts while keeping the wheel in contact with the ground or obstacle, thereby maintaining traction & control. Suspension seatpost is mostly about rider comfort.  Don't seem to  be as popular as in the past.

Answer (score 1):

Suspension seatposts have always been a niche product, but in my view are now a niche that is redundant for mountain biking, and perhaps more suited to a gravel bike.

In recent years we have seen widespread adoption of larger wheel diameters (27.5/29") and high volume tubeless tyres.  Fat bikes and 'plus' bikes in particular are known for their plush magic carpet like ride quality with the large low pressure tyres deforming round objects greatly smoothing the ride and providing a surprisingly low rolling resistance off road.

10 years ago I would have been running 26x1.9" tyres at 40psi, and a suspension seatpost would have seemed a great idea.  These days i'm running 29x2.2" or 27.5x2.4" at 22psi  and 27.5x2.8" at 14psi and even on a hardtail have never even contemplated a suspension seatpost.